# Using jquery post for mvc 3 not working when deployed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I've got this MVC 3 application that has a dropdown that I use to populate a div via jquery. It works fine locally but when I deploy it to the server it's redirecting incorrectly. Here's my jquery:

```
$("#ddlCategoryMain").change(function () {
    $.post("/Home/Category/", { mileID: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        refreshDiv($("div#main"), data);
    });
});

function refreshDiv(select, data) {
    select.html("");
    select.append(data);
}
```

Locally this works fine. But when deployed to my server it appears to be looking for http://myserver/Home/Category instead of http://myserver/mywebsite/Home/Category

I can fix it by simply adding the name of my application before the /Home/Category in the jquery function, but that doesn't feel right...

I've also tried to add ../, ~/, ../../ before the /Home but that made no difference.

Any solutions to this minor problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Option 1**

Assuming your jQuery method is in your view you can use [`Url.Action()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758.aspx)

> Generates a fully qualified URL to an
>   action method by using the specified
>   action name and controller name.

```
$("#ddlCategoryMain").change(function () {
    $.post('<%=Url.Action("Category", "Home")%>', { mileID: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        refreshDiv($("#main"), data);
    });
});
```

Or this if you are using razor

```
$("#ddlCategoryMain").change(function () {
    $.post('@Url.Action("Category", "Home")', { mileID: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        refreshDiv($("#main"), data);
    });
});
```

**Option 2**

If the method is in an external js file you could declare a global variable in your view.

```
var myUrl = '@Url.Action("Category", "Home")';
```

and then in your `$.post`

```
$("#ddlCategoryMain").change(function () {
    $.post(myUrl , { mileID: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        refreshDiv($("#main"), data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first option is something I was looking into but somehow must have done wrong as it wasn't working. It now does!

Comment: Does anyone know why its not working without URL.action()?

Answer (score 2):

We were facing the same issue when we deployed the code on the server, locally it worked really fine so this helped us alot.

We are using Razor and that's what we were doing:

```
$.post("/Home/PostEditProduct/", { } ...
```

and now replaced with

```
$.post('@Url.Action("PostEditProduct","Home")', { } ...
```

and it works.

Comment: Using @Url.Action(..) is always a good decision with MVC! Never hardcode the path, so you can change the routes dynamically afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but this is how I do it on my Zend MVC site, when I add my jQuery - I set a var as the base URL - then in the ajax call, place the var in front of the path.

So for me I would do:

```
    $this->jQuery()->addOnLoad('var baseURL = "'.$this->baseUrl('').'";');
```

Then I could use;

```
    $.post(baseURL+"/Home/Category/"......
```