# How to get jQuery.Ajax to perform a normal POST with a redirect using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I currently have a JSON object on my page which gets built up as users add items to it. This is all done in JavaScript/jQuery.

When the user is done adding items, I want to POST this object to a controller action and have the action return a strongly typed view using this data.

Currently, I have the jQuery.ajax POST sending this JSON object to an Action Method which then binds this object to my strongly typed Model. Problem is, I actually want this jQuery.ajax POST to redirect as if the JSON object were in a FORM and simply being submitted.

I also can't use the jQuery.post() method, which would redirect as required, as I need to be able to set the contentType to "application/json" so my binding works correctly. Unfortunately, the jQuery.post() method doesn't allow you to set this parameter.

I've read that the jQuery.post() method basically uses the jQuery.ajax() method, so I've been battling to get the jQuery.ajax() method to redirect.

I've also read that I can set the default contentType for all jQuery.ajax() methods which would then allow me to use the jQuery.post() method but want to try avoid this if possible.

Thanks

**Edit: Updated with Saedeas suggestion:**

My JavaScript on the 'Index' View:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    //  Initialize the Shopping Cart object
    var m_ShoppingCart = {
        UserId: 10,
        DeliveryInstructions: "Leave at front desk",
        CartItems: []
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.extend({
            postJSON: function (url, data, callback) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: callback,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    processData: false
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function PostDataWithRedirect() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("ConfirmOrder", "Store")';
                $.postJSON(url, m_ShoppingCart, function () { });
    }

    function AddToCart(id, itemName, price, quantity) {

        //  Add the item to the shopping cart object
        m_ShoppingCart.CartItems.push({
            "Id": id,
            "ItemName": itemName,
            "Price": price.toFixed(2), //   Issue here if you don't specify the decimal     place
            "Quantity": quantity
        });

        //  Render the shopping cart object
        RenderShoppingCart();
    }



    function RenderShoppingCart() {

        $("#CartItemList").html("");

        var totalAmount = 0;

        $.each(m_ShoppingCart.CartItems, function (index, cartItem) {

            var itemTotal = Number(cartItem.Price) * Number(cartItem.Quantity);
            totalAmount += itemTotal;

            $("#CartItemList").append("<li>" + cartItem.ItemName + " - $" +     itemTotal.toFixed(2) + "</li>");
        });

        $("#TotalAmount").html("$" + totalAmount.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

And then the Controller Action 'ConfirmOrder'

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmOrder(ShoppingCartModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

So when the PostDataWithRedirect() JavaScript method is called it must hit the ConfirmOrder Controller Action and be redirected to the ConfirmOrder View. The Shopping Cart object on my Index view is built up entirely in JavaScript and the user then clicks a 'Proceed to Checkout' button and is redirected etc.

PS: My full working example can be found in an the article [ [How to POST a JSON object in MVC](http://www.webcognoscere.com/post/2012/07/03/How-to-POST-a-JSON-object-to-a-Controller-Action.aspx) ], I just need to update this code so that it can do the post and redirect as explained above

Comment: in your callback from jQuery.ajax() can't you just submit() the form with the data you want?

Comment: I don't have a form on my page

Comment: You could emit a form on the fly in jquery with the data in hidden values with the correct field names and then `submit()` it - that would trigger the browser's 'normal' post-navigate behaviour.  The simplicity of the code will depend on the complexity of the object you need to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a view that redirects:

controller

```
return View("redirectionView");
```

view

```
RedirectionView.cshtml
@{
Layout = null;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Success! Redirecting...");
  window.location = "./";
</script>
```

**EDIT**

To accommodate data retention use tempdata.

controller

```
TempData["collectedUserData"] = collectedData;
return View("redirectionView");
```

RedirectionView.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("Success! Redirecting...");
 window.location = "./Rebuilder/ActionMethod";
</script>
```

Controller Rebuilder

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod()
{
 if( TempData.ContainsKey("collectedUserData") )
 {
  var collectedData = TempData["collectedUserData"];
 }
 //todo: use else clause to catch data not present
         use collectedData to build new view
 return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Travis J, I wanted to stay away from using temp storage and just get the ajax post to post the data and redirect but it seems there's no ways to actually do this. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 6):

In the success method, do a `location.href = "TARGET LOCATION"` to cause the page to go to `TARGET LOCATION`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: myurl,data,
    data: myData,
    // processData: false, // you may need this option depending on service setup
    success: function(){
        location.href = "TARGET LOCATION";
    },
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: I can't use the $.post method as mentioned as I need to set the contentType and the post method doesn't have that option.

Comment: so... use the ajax method? it's the same concept.

Comment: It's the success callback I think.

    $.ajax({
        success:function(){

        }
    });

Comment: @KevinB - thx for the help, but I need the ajax method to behave as a normal post, i.e. POST and redirect to a url, i.e. Page A compiles a JSON object and POSTS to Page B, which renders that object. If I use location.href as suggested it will just redirect to Page B, without the data, and since my Controller Action for Page B only accepts [POST] it breaks before that as the location.href does a GET and not a POST.

Comment: @Nikron You can still do a [POST] using `$.ajax`. As a matter of fact, `$.post` uses `$.ajax` to make it's request.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm not following the question, but why does the classic post, redirect, get pattern not work?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult WhateverActionName()
{
    YourViewModel yvm = new YourViewModel();
    //Initalize viewmodel here
    Return view(yvm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult WhateverActionName(YourViewModel yvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        RedirectToAction("OtherAction", "OtherController")
    }
    return View(yvm);
}
```

Do you mean you want to do a post, have it bind to the viewmodel for validation purposes in one controller, and then have that controller post to another controller that verifies everything?  If so, I suggest taking a look at this code to post in c# http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx.

Edit:  Or you could just place the data in a tempdata object if the other controller action doesn't truly require a post.

Edit 2:  Wait, is the question how to do the post with jquery? If so,

```
$("#YourForm").submit(function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("WhateverActionName", "YourController")';
    });
});
```

Note: may be small syntax errors, but close to that.  The @Url.Action is the important part.

Edit 3:  This should finally work.

```
jQuery.extend({
    postJSON: function(url, data, callback) {
      return jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: callback,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false
      });
    }
  });
```

Call it in your view as

```
$.postJSON('@URL.Action("Action", "Controller")', yourJson, callback)
```

And then redirect inside the controller.

Comment: Hi saedeas, the question is how to do a post with jquery and have it redirect like a standard post. So in essence post a json object to URL A having the user getting redirected to A.D

Comment: Ahh, in that case, you can mix razor or aspx into your jquery to specify the controller you want to post to and you can redirect inside that controller.  Basically, set your controller up like my bottom one up there and post to it from the jquery using the @URL.Action().  Here's a relevant link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251992/using-jquery-post-for-mvc-3-not-working-when-deployed.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally, if you need to pass the data to the controller you redirect to, use tempdata.

Comment: Hi saedeas, the question is how to do a post with jquery and have it redirect like a standard post. So in essence post a json object to URL A having the user get redirected to URL A. and not a Ajax post then a plain redirect, it has to post while getting redirected to that page as that pages controller action takes the posted data and returns a view with that data.

Comment: So, to be clear.  Say you are in View A, you want to post from that view to a Controller Action linked to View B using jquery?    Or do you want to post to View A's Controller action, and then redirect to a Controller action linked to View B?  Or, lastly, do you want to post to View A's controller action, and then from that, post to View B' controller action?  Is there any reason Asp.net MVC server side redirects are bad?  Does the redirect need to take place client side based on a server response, or regardless of server response?

Comment: Basically, I'm just confused as to why you can't just post whatever data you have to whatever controller you please using $.post('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")');.  The server can perform the redirect for you at that point.  Alternatively, you can return a callback to the post and redirect using jquery, but that seems complicated and unnecessary.

Comment: So if I could use the $.post method and have it post my json object to my controller action that would be perfect as my controller action would take my json object, map it to my model and load up my view. Problem is that the $.post won't work as it can't send the json object as you cannot set the content type on the $.post method.

Comment: Ahh, let me edit in a little extension method that should work.

Comment: This is my fundamental problem. I need the behavior of the $.post (the redirect as part of the post) but it won't work as the controller action doesn't understand the content type correctly and therefore can't bind my json object automatically to my model. If I use $.ajax I get the automatic binding working but not the redirect. And I can't just do a redirect when the response comes back as part of the post process is to load up a new view with the data from my Json object

Comment: Thanks Saedeas, that looks like it might do the trick. I'll let you know tomorrow as I'm not by my pc ATM. Thanks a mil for your help thus far, really appreciate it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13882/discussion-between-nikron-and-saedeas)

Comment: I still can't get this to redirect